# How to Use Kubernetes Multiple Commands and Arguments without passing scripts

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to create a pod using yaml file, that can run few commands as soon as it started. The yaml files looks like:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testmultiplecmds
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: nginxmultiplecmds
    image: nginx
    command:
    - "/bin/bash"
    - -c
    - "ls -ltr"
    - "/bin/bash"
    - -c
    args:
    - "date ; sleep 36"
```

but everytime I run this, it only outputs the results of /bin/bash -c ls -ltr, which is basically the first command and everything else is ignored. I tried multiple combination like:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testmultiplecmds
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: nginxmultiplecmds
    image: nginx
    command:
    - "/bin/bash"
    - -c
    args:
    - "date ;"
    - "sleep 30"
```

but in this also, it just prints out the date and does not sleep.
But when I do:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testmultiplecmds
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: nginxmultiplecmds
    image: nginx
    command:
    - "/bin/bash"
    - -c
    args:
    - "date ; sleep 30"
```

it works.

So my question is, Why we cannot run multiple commands (specified in different lines as different items not under single string) even though **commands** and **args** takes []String and if we cannot run multiple commands, then why they take []String, they should simply take String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you describes is caused by the mere fact of how bash works, and its all documented behaviour.

Let's consider this example:

```
command:
- "/bin/bash"
- -c
- "ls -ltr"
- "/bin/bash"
- -c
args:
- "date ; sleep 36"
```

It is equal to the following command you would run in your terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "ls -ltr" "/bin/bash" -c "date ; sleep 36"
```

What happens is you start bash and pass arguments: `-c` `"ls -ltr"` and this instructs bash to run `ls`. Next argument is "/bin/bash" string that is passed to bash command which looks like its being ignored by the bash executable. So are ignored all consecutive arguments.

Let's have a look at what bash docs says about `-c` option:

> If the -c option is present, then **commands are read from the first
> non-option argument command_string**.   **If there  are arguments after
> the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any
> remaining argu‐ ments are assigned to the positional parameters**.  The
> assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning
> and error messages.

So the arguments after the *command_string* are not ignored, they are passed to the command as arguments.

ok, let's see what happens if we echo $0 and $1 in following example:

```
➜  ~ bash -c 'echo $0 $1' -c "echo 456"
-c echo 456
```

Notice that string `-c` got assigned to $0 and `"echo 456"` got assigned to $1; just as described in documentation.

Do you see now how this works?

It's not how pods work nor how k8s works. It's bash specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testmultiplecmds
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: nginxmultiplecmds
    image: nginx
    command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    args: ["date; sleep 30"]
```

`["/bin/bash", "-c"]` meaning run a bash to execute following instructions. And passed commands by args. The args are then passed as commands to the bash. Commnads are separated in args by semicolon.

## update

for multiline you can give args like this way, every command should end with a semicolon.

```
args:
   - date;
     sleep 10;
     echo done;
```

Comment: yeah but u passed args as a single String, it works like that. But my question was when I tried to pass it as a list it does not works

Comment: Why is this one not working:
`
args:
    - "date ;"
    - "sleep 30"
`

Comment: can you try with avoiding the quotes and also add semicolon at the end of last command also

Comment: I tried as you said, but it only printed out the date and it didnt sleep.

`
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testmultiplecmds
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: nginxmultiplecmds
    image: nginx
    command:
    - "/bin/bash"
    - -c
    args:
    - date ; 
    - sleep 30;
`

Comment: Here is the kubectl get pods output:
testmultiplecmds                       0/1     Completed   0          5s

Comment: basically sleep didn't work cause you use two `-`,  you need to put all the commands in args under a list (`-`) as yaml concatenates all the lines under a "-" into one and pass that to bash, basically again it creates a string.

Comment: yeah thats what my question is, if it does not work like that, then why the definition of args says it accepts []String. It should only take String? same goes for command as well (my first yaml file that I pasted in the question).

Comment: @AnxiousGuy: Frankly this is a meaningless point you are trying to dig, I feel Sahadat has answered it in the best possible way, in my opinion you may consider accepting the answer, I don't see any point in chewing this gum endlessly.

Comment: @hagrawal, it may sound meaningless to you, but its not for me. Rather saying meaningless to one's anxiety we should try to provide answers just like what "Matt" did.

Comment: @AnxiousGuy I think I unintentionally hurt your feelings, actually, my point was this was a trifling point to dig so deep, but sure I should have not commented on anyone's curiosity, I take my word back on "meaningless".

Comment: @hagrawal, yeah sure no problem. Thank you for understanding :)